# what is the network bandwidth of a virtual nic?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, hardware-virtualization, virtual-machine-manager

I am trying to do communication between two VMs hosted on one server. I want to know what is the maximum bandwidth capacity of virtual nics ? I am using virtual machine manager.

Comment: It would usually only be limited by available resources (CPU, memory, buses).

Comment: This could be limited by the kind of NIC that is being simulated.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum bandwidth between two VMs on the same host is only limited by the hardware, especially CPU if nothing is being written to the disk with that network traffic. It does not matter if the NIC in e.g. a virtualized Windows XP only shows 10MBit/s - it will go far beyond that. There is no "hard" limit for the network speed between VMs, except if you configure one.